# How to make didSelectRowAt IndexPath work with custom delegate

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, didselectrowatindexpath

Alright, so i have a ViewController with a `UITableView` in it. Before moving on with the coding i read that in order to get actions from buttons or have a custom cell you can either use tags or use a more cleaner solution using protocol & delegates. Obviously i choose the latter one.

Now when i use a custom `UITableViewCell` which is called `TableViewCellsDelegate` in my class `ViewController` i need to replace it with UITableViewDelegate in the code below as you can see:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource, TableViewCellsDelegate{} ....
```

My problem is that i have this function that is now not being called:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("in here")
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        if dateCellExpanded {
            dateCellExpanded = false
        } else {
            dateCellExpanded = true
        }
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

I doubt that if you choose to have a custom UITableViewCell you loose some of the delegate functions. There has to be some solution. Here is my `TableViewCellsDelegate`

```
protocol TableViewCellsDelegate : class {
    func bookTapped(_ sender: UIButton)
    func unbookTapped(_ sender: UIButton)
}

    class TableViewCells: UITableViewCell {


        @IBOutlet var bookButtonProperties: UIButton!

        @IBOutlet var unbookButtonProperties: UIButton!

        @IBOutlet var nameField: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet var numberField: UITextField!

        weak var delegate: TableViewCellsDelegate?

        @IBAction func bookPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
            delegate?.bookTapped(sender)
        }

       @IBAction func unbookPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
            delegate?.unbookTapped(sender)
        }
    }
```

Comment: [`tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614877-tableview) is a method of `UITableViewDelegate`. So you need conformance to `UITableViewDelegate` to have the call back inside `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`

Comment: `didSelectRowAt` will get called when you select the cell, but in your case, you have controls like `UIButton` and `UITextField` which are derived from `UIControl`, means when you tap on these control your tap doesn't go to the cell, and it leads to `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` not being called. On the other hand, there might be possible that UITableView delegate is not being properly set to `viewController`

Comment: This is not the case @deoKasuhal as i said when i changed in my 'ViewController'  from TableViewCellsDelegate to UITableViewDelegate ,then didSelect was called(all the outlets you mentioned are still there). So i get that i need UITableViewDelegate but what i was looking for a fix for this or do i have to remodel my coding

Comment: @TimoCengiz, `UITableViewDelegate` is with `UITableView` and `TableViewCellsDelegate` is associated with `UITableViewCell`. The code for delegate should be set to `ViewController` one using `UITableView` and another one using `UITableViewCell` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  Looking into the code one thing is missing that you haven't extended `UITableViewDelegate` into your viewController. 
`class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource, TableViewCellsDelegate, UITableViewDelegate {}`

Comment: @deoKasuhal Ok so i am pretty pissed off. I remember trying to put 'UITableViewDelegate' but i got an error so i thought that it was not possible. When i read your commend i had a feeling that the position 'UITableViewDelegate' has is important. Why do i get an error if i put if the order is : 'UIViewController, 'UITableViewDataSource', 'UITableViewDelegate', 'TableViewCellsDelegate' ?, otherwise thank you it now works. That is why i did not understand the others cause i felt that i had aready tried it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use UITableViewDelegate in place of TableViewCellsDelegate to work the didSelectRowAt.

If you have any questions call me back.

Comment: I did understand what i need to do. Can you clear things up with some more explanation?

Comment: of course, didSelectRowAt is a delegate of the tableView and not the UITableViewCell so you need to add UITableViewDelegate with UITableViewDataSource on implementing a tableview in a viewController, You can read more about these two links https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate   https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/

Comment: Yes i know this. My question was if i am using a custom UITableViewCell which makes me not be able to put UITableViewDelegate there, how can i solve it?

Comment: Uitableviewdelegate need to implemented in a UITableViewCell type class and not the ViewController, the ViewController you will work with the tableView.  class CustomTableCellClass: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {...}  in tableView delegates  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
    let cell = tableView.dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell",    forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableCellClass
   
    return cell
}. If I misunderstood, attach more information in your question so that I can help:)

Comment: added explanation for better understanding my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better to make notification, I'm trying to make delegate Method, but this if you don't need to give parameters, as for me its better way to do this

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let internetDown = Notification.Name("internetDown")
}
```

to subscribe

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(performDeinit), name: .internetDown, object: nil)
```

to send:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .internetDown, object: nil, userInfo: nil)
```